# Collection Fetch making n*n views when only n is required

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, many-to-many

I am a beginner with backbonejs. I have created a message-view and a message-view-collection
like

```
var MessageViewCollection = Backbone.View.extend({
            initialize: function(options) {
                this.options = options;
                this.$el = $(options.el);
                // this.render();
                //this._addButton(this.options);

                // this.model.on('change', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('add', this.render, this);
                this.model.on('remove', this.render, this);

            // --> this.model is a collection : it has n models, which it fetches. 
                this.model.fetch({
                    success: function() {
                        console.log('Successfully fetched all messages');
                    },
                    error: function(err) {
                        console.log('Failed to fetch messages ' + err);
                    }
                });
            },
            render: function() {
                var self = this;
                this.$el.html('');
                // This button is getting rendered again ang again - can move the renderCollection.
                this._addButton(this.options);
                _.each(this.model.toArray(), function(message, i){
                    self.$el.append((new MessageView({model: message})).render().$el);
                });
                return this; 
            }
        });
```

This view is rendered in the starting. I found that when it fetches, it has n models. For each model, it creates  a `MesageView` . But it seems to create n*n message views.
and at last only n are appended to the DOM.

Their is only one network call that fetches this collection of n models.
This seems to be a waste of client-side resources, memory, processing, power.

I think that i am listening on 'add' to this collection, which is causing render to be called each time, it adds to the collection. Is that the problem ?

How do i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Every time you add something to the collection, you are running render again and therefore iterating over the entire collection.

So what you should do it's to create a render function for a single model.

```
this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.renderMessage, this);

renderMessage: function(message) {
    this.$el.append((new MessageView({model: message})).render().$el);
}
```

And of course, to avoid confusion you shouldn't call model to what should be called collection...

Comment: how would i handle the remove, creating a new function that reads the whole collection and _.each adds to the el. ?

Comment: For that I would listen for the 'remove' event inside of the **MessageView** like `this.listenTo(this.model, 'remove', this.close, this);` and then you can create a close function where you call `this.remove();` and `this.unbind();`.